# increment php variable in javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

Can anyone tell me how to increment a php variable inside a javascript function.I have a javascript function which is called for every 3 seconds inside this function i need to increment the php variable.

```
<? php $k =0?>
function slide()
{
 //increment $k
 var j =<? php echo $k++; ?>//when I do this k is not incremented
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?Is their any other alternative to do this?

Thanks,

Shruti

Comment: That's definitely not going to work because by the time the JS is doing it's thing (client-side), PHP is already done (server-side). What are you trying to achieve overall?

Comment: $k++ says use $k in the current operation, and then increment it. So in the outputted JS you would see j being set to 0. To have j set to 1, You could do ++$k which would increment $k, then use it in the current operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is run on the Server, Javascript is client side.  What I think you want is a way to increment the JS value using Javascript not PHP.

The users never see php, so there is no incrementation happening.

You need to have a javascript function (clock) that keeps track of your 3 seconds, and then increase the value of your javascript `var j` every elapsed period (if I understood your questions correctly).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you don't.

Longer answer: PHP runs *and only* when the page is first loaded. This code is executed on the server.
Javascript on the other hand is executed after the page has finished loading, inside the browser **on the client's computer**.

Maybe someone can give some advice if you tell us what exactly are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is serverside, Javascript is clientside. You can't mix apples and oranges and expect bananas. Two things work in a different way. Use JS if you need JS variable incremented.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment the variable before you print it:

```
<?php echo ++$k; ?>
```

Comment: Perhaps, but I think you missed the key problem here ;-)

Comment: I intentionally overlooked the mixing PHP with JS and just offered a solution to the raw problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can return k from php and increment it in Javascript. Have your code like this:

```
<script>
<?php $k=5; echo "var k=$k;\n";?>
function slide()
{
 //increment k
 var j = k++; //k is incremented ONLY in javascript and j get's the k's value
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can do something like this:
<?php 
$options= array('option1', 'option2','option3','option4');
?>

/* in the same file you can convert an array php into an array javascript with json_encode() php function*/

<script>

/*In this way you can read all the javascript array from php array*/

var options_javascript =<?php echo json_encode($options); ?>;

/*And you can increase javascript variables. For example:*/

    for(var i =0; i<options_javascript.length; i++ ){
        options_javascript[i];
    }

</script>
```